# Table not sorting when the value is from the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My problem is if the value of table is from the database the table is not sorting.

```
    $sql=("SELECT *,SUM(unit_cost*quantity) AS total_amount FROM procurement WHERE rfq LIKE '13-___' GROUP BY counter ORDER BY rfq");
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    echo'<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th title="RFQ"></th>
                <th title="RFQ">RFQ #</th>
                <th title="Item Name">Item Name</th>
                <th title="Item Description">Description</th>
                <th title="Example : Pc, Pcs, Box and Etc.">Unit</th>
                <th title="Item Price">Unit Cost</th>
                <th title="Total Item Quantity">QTY</th>
                <th title="Total Price">Total Amount</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     echo'  <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="comments.php?pn='.$row["rfq"].'"><img src="images/remarks.png" border="0" width="10" height="10" title="Remarks and Notes"></a></td>
                <td>'.$row['rfq'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['item_description'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['unit'].'</td>
                <td>'.number_format($row['unit_cost'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
                <td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td>
                <td>'.number_format($row['total_amount'], 2, '.', ',').'</td></tr></tbody>';
            }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

But when the value of table does not came from the database it's works perfectly. What should I do?

```
        <tr>
            <th>Major</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>English</th>
            <th>Japanese</th>
            <th>Calculus</th>
            <th>Geometry</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Student01</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student02</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>88</td>
            <td></td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student03</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>80</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I got the script from http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Javascript can't tell where the data came from, all it sees is the HTML. Please post the HTML that's causing the problem, and your Javascript.

Comment: You have the `order by` in the SQL, which is how the results will be sorted. If you aren't wanting to sort by `rfq`, you should have it in the statement what you want to sort by.

Comment: @Fluffeh That's just the initial order, he's using a JS plugin to allow the user to re-sort it. The problem, as Deepak pointed out, is that he's starting a new `<tbody>` on every row.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `<tbody>` out of the `while` loop.

Try this code,

```
$sql=("SELECT *,SUM(unit_cost*quantity) AS total_amount FROM procurement WHERE rfq LIKE '13-___' GROUP BY counter ORDER BY rfq");
$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo'<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th title="RFQ"></th>
            <th title="RFQ">RFQ #</th>
            <th title="Item Name">Item Name</th>
            <th title="Item Description">Description</th>
            <th title="Example : Pc, Pcs, Box and Etc.">Unit</th>
            <th title="Item Price">Unit Cost</th>
            <th title="Total Item Quantity">QTY</th>
            <th title="Total Price">Total Amount</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo'<tr>
            <td align="center"><a href="comments.php?pn='.$row["rfq"].'"><img src="images/remarks.png" border="0" width="10" height="10" title="Remarks and Notes"></a></td>
            <td>'.$row['rfq'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['item_description'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['unit'].'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($row['unit_cost'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
            <td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($row['total_amount'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
       </tr>';
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: woah ! that was GREAT ! it works :), can you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: You're starting a new table body for every row. The table should just have one body.

Comment: the problem is your code was generating `<tbody>` for each loop which means you are creating as many body as your '<tr>` tags. The java script will look for set of `<tr>` tags in a `<tbody>` which in you case is gonna be only one for each `<tbody>` leaving the table unsortable.. Accept if that helps!!