# Mysql Table Sorting in Php (Client side)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Can any one help how to sort the database results in php
i have pasted the my code below. it display the result but sorting cannot be done.

Any help in this regard

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var sortedOn = 0;

function SortTable(sortOn) {

    var table = document.getElementById('results');
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    var rowArray = new Array();
    for (var i=0, length=rows.length; i<length; i++) {
        rowArray[i] = rows[i].cloneNode(true);
    }

    if (sortOn == sortedOn) { rowArray.reverse(); }
    else {
        sortedOn = sortOn;
        if (sortedOn == 0) {
            rowArray.sort(RowCompareNumbers);
        }
        else if (sortedOn == 3) {
            rowArray.sort(RowCompareDollars);
        }
        else {
            rowArray.sort(RowCompare);
        }
    }

    var newTbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    for (var i=0, length=rowArray.length; i<length; i++) {
        newTbody.appendChild(rowArray[i]);
    }

    table.replaceChild(newTbody, tbody);
}

function RowCompare(a, b) {

    var aVal = a.getElementsByTagName('td')[sortedOn].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var bVal = b.getElementsByTagName('td')[sortedOn].firstChild.nodeValue;
    return (aVal == bVal ? 0 : (aVal > bVal ? 1 : -1));
}

function RowCompareNumbers(a, b) { 


    var aVal = parseInt(a.getElementsByTagName('td') 
     [sortedOn].firstChild.nodeValue);
    var bVal = parseInt(b.getElementsByTagName('td')

    [sortedOn].firstChild.nodeValue);
    return (aVal - bVal);
}

function RowCompareDollars(a, b) {

    var aVal = parseFloat(a.getElementsByTagName('td') 
       [sortedOn].firstChild.nodeValue.substr(1));
    var bVal = parseFloat(b.getElementsByTagName('td')
        [sortedOn].firstChild.nodeValue.substr(1));
    return (aVal - bVal);
}

//-->
</script>
```

Php MySql Query

```
 <?php
 $job_id = $_GET['id'] ;
 $sql="SELECT date, fullname, city, education from table_name
 WHERE  id = 'job_id'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql); ?>


 <table id="results" style="width:980px;">
<thead>
 <tr>
 <th style="width:60px;"><a onclick="SortTable(0);" href="javascript:;">Date</a></th>
  <th style="width:150px;"><a onclick="SortTable(1);" href="javascript:;">Name</a></th>
 <th style="width:70px;"><a onclick="SortTable(2);" href="javascript:;">City</a></th>
 <th style="width:70px;"><a onclick="SortTable(3);"href="javascript:;">Education</a>   
 </th>
```

```
<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

?>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>   
<td><? echo $fullname ; ?></td>
<td><? echo $city ; ?></td> 
<td><? echo $b_education ; ?></td> 

</tr>

</tbody>



<?
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: What happens when you debug this?  In what way does your `SortTable` function not work?  Where specifically does the runtime behavior of the code differ from what you expect?

Comment: i think the problem is with loop function.

Comment: i think the problem is with loop function. sorting happens only for 1st column

Answer (score 0):

```
 $job_id = $_GET['id'] ;
 $sql="SELECT date, fullname, city, education from table_name
 WHERE  id = 'job_id'";
```

will not work, 
first it should id = '" . $job_id . "' (your WHERE condition search for the id "job_id" not the $job_id variable

2nd based on this lines, google the words "sql injection" ... thats a big security issue! (msyql_real_escape for example)

3rd, mysql provides ORDER functions... if you want client side order, build the result, convert it to json (json_encode) and handle it with javascript, but yours is crappy ^^

regards
Thomas

Comment: Hi Thomas, Database results are displayed perfectly. but i am not able to sort the database results client side. do you have any code for that. i am very new to javacript and php

Comment: now i am able to sort the results client side. thanks to below mentioned post.                                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018626/table-not-sorting-when-the-value-is-from-the-database